# Is there a rule for what the plural of a noun will be based on the noun?

Tags: noun, grammatical-number

Perhaps this is a very naive question — and it certainly seems to me to be, but I’ve found German to be a very rule-based, orderly language in many regards, so I just thought I’d make sure — but is there a way to tell what the plural of a noun is based on the ending, or some combination of that and gender, or just a rough rule that sometimes works, or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There are many rules (see. e.g. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Substantive), especially subheading *Grundsätze*) and since one does not see, whether a substantive belongs to strong or weak declension, this always has to be looked up.

Special attention is required for some words having two plural forms (as *Worte* vs. *Wörter*), since their meaning may be different.